# Laravel excel downloading data without column heading

Tags: excel, laravel, composer-php, laravel-blade

I am using laravel 7. For excel download I am using laravel excel ( documentation: https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/getting-started/) but It only downloading the data in xlsx file, there is no column heading. I want column heading with the data.

UserExport file in App/Exports

```
 public function collection()
{
    $user=DB::table('admin')->get();
    return $user;
}
```

controller function:

```
public function export() 
{
    return Excel::download(new UsersExport, 'users.xlsx');
}
```

How can I add column headings of admin table here?

Comment: See this page, will it help? https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel/issues/1695

Comment: What have you tried so far to make this work? And how is this related to Composer?